# Enthought canopy code editor namespace warnings

Tags: python, syntax, canopy

Canopy code editor underlines the variables that are undefined. However, once variables are loaded to the namespace by running another python script from the current script, it still does the error highlighting even though such variable exists and can be used.

Is there any way to make it see the loaded variables too?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is not, and should not be, because as the script runs, it won't have access to those variables.

For more information, please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26413862/1988991

You *can* run a script in the ipython shell namespace by using the Run magic's `-i` option, but this is not the normal usage, nor is it useful for testing a script which will be run independently.

Comment: Alright, thanks. By the way, I can use those variables when I run another python script from my current script with the command 'execfile()'.

Comment: Your wording is a bit vague and as I read it, incorrect. To be precise: you can use the ipython namespace in test.py if you `execfile("test.py")` from the ipython shell. You cannot use the ipython namespace in test.py if you execfile it inside of a running script as you seem to indicate. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile . Bottom line: when you %run a script, neither it, nor anything it uses, can access the ipython namespace using ordinary means. BTW FYI: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work